# Определить источник проблем сервера

Tags: сервер

У меня такой вопрос - как можно определить присутствует ли на сервере проблема с интернет каналом??

Ситуация: есть выделенный сервер, с достаточно хорошими параметрами - процессор, память, и т.д.

Проблема: время от времени сервер становится плохо доступным, то есть страницы загружаются очень долго, по 10-15 секунд, консоль по SSH некоторое время не реагирует ни на что. Длится это несколько минут, а затем всё проходит, и скажем всё что я печатал появляется в консоли, страница подгружается и т.д.

Comment: Уточните операционную систему.

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Здесь довольно обширная задача. Проблемы могут быть где угодно, начиная от ошибок на физическом/канальном уровне, и заканчивая тем, что периодически кем-то генерируется огромнейший объём трафика, который забивает канал.

Что нужно сделать в первую очередь?

**Проанализировать файлы-журналов (log-файлы)**

Исследовать все лог-файлы системы на наличие ошибок сетевого интерфейса/ядра.
В зависимости от системы это может быть:

- `/var/log/syslog`
- `/var/log/messages`
- `/var/log/kern.log`

Кроме того есть программа `dmesg`, которая показывает вам вывод ядра.

**Проанализировать ошибки на сетевых интерфейсах**

Статистику по сетевым интерфейсам (количество ошибок)
можно просмотреть командами:

```
ifconfig
netstat -i
netstat -p (информация о tcp)
```

Возможно там вы увидите, что пакеты приходят битыми, не приходят, так далее.

**Чётко конкретизировать сбой, проанализировать возможные его источники**

Нужно проанализировать все симптомы проявляющего сбоя и выяснить, в чём именно они выражаются, какие подсистемы могут быть затронуты.

В частности:

- является ли проблема сугубо сетевой или затронуты и локальные процессы;
- на каких направлениях возникает проблема;
- каких протоколов касается проблема;
- есть ли какая-то временная закономерность в появлении сбоя;
  и так далее.

**Проанализировать поведение системы в момент/период сбоя**

Нужно посмотреть, что происходит с системой, когда 
начинается сбойный период, т.е. когда она плохо работает.

Нужно пропинговать её в этот момент, посмотреть, теряются ли пинги.

Если теряются, проверить систему с помощью `traceroute`, возможно пакеты теряются по дороге.

С помощью `trafshow` посмотреть, нет ли аномально высокого трафика в этот момент.

С помощью `top`/`htop`/`sar` посмотреть, нет ли аномально активных процессов в этот момент.

Если сбой происходит не часто и возможности интерактивного вмешательства в него нет, нужно по максимум настроить все системы мониторинга + системы автоматического обнуражения сбоя (например, пинги начали пропадать или усилилась нагрузка на канал и так далее; короче нужно написать скрипт, который будет фиксировать ожидаемое событие и информировать о наступлении сбоя).

Собранная статистика поможет ответить на поставленные вопросы и существенно локализовать проблему. Когда проблему будет локализована, решить её будет очень просто.

Comment: Голосую, крайне информативен

Comment: @GrayHoax: Будем надеяться, это поможет Toly хоть чуть-чуть разобраться с его проблемой. Кстати, если вы будете ему помогать, хорошо бы потом выложить описание в чём была проблема в ваш ответ. Это бы могло в будущем пригодиться кому-то

Comment: Согласен. Опубликую общим, если владелец даст согласие.

Comment: В момент когда сервер не доступен - консоль не отвечает. Поэтому команды вроде top - не доступны. Потом сервер отвисает - я смотрю top, а там всё нормально. Сейчас посмотрю другие логи, указанные вами - может действительно есть какие-либо ошибки.

Comment: @Toly: Что не отвечает консоль, это не страшно. Я написал в последнем шаге, что нужно делать. Нужно заранее настроить сбор информации, которую позже можно проанализировать

Comment: Да, спасибо. Сейчас буду разбираться со всем что вы написали )), там много чего надо проверить и посмотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема может быть связана не только с интернет-каналом.

Есть стандартная утилита top, которой можно проверить Состояние загрузки процессора и занятой памяти. Её более интересный аналог - htop

Для проверки работы интернет-канала, попробуйте закачать, а потом скачать большой файл, более 1 Гб. Вы сразу увидите скорость работы канала в динамике. Но будьте внимательны здесь может быть проблема и с Вашим каналом, т.е. у Вас соединение с интернет может лагать. От чего и проблемы...

И конечно лучше использовать мониторинг для таких целей. Я установил на свой VPS zabbix и вижу свой трафик на интерфейсе. При этом сразу заметны скачки, а график использования процессора сразу позволяет определить с чем проблема. Но сервер мониторинга нужно устанавливать вне виртуального сервера, который мониторится.

Comment: Спасибо про идею про загрузку большого файла. Сейчас разберусь с логами, и если не найду проблему - попробую так. Команда top не доступна пока сервер не отвиснет, но стабильно показывает что есть куча свободных ресурсов - процессор, память.  Zabbix - думаю если ничего не поможет - попробую установить этот мониторинг.

Comment: Заметьте, что этот мониторинг состоит из двух частей, серверной и клиентской. Вам может помочь даже если Вы установите на своём сервере, но будет кушать ресурсы.

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте на сервер [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) и [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

Первый рисует графики: загрузку процессоров, свободную память, обращения к диску, ошибки сетевого интерфейса — оч. много графиков. Вероятно, поможет понять причину очередного сбоя. И вообще приятно наблюдать.

Второй следит за тем, чтобы сервисы работали, порты отвечали, и если что не так, выполняет перезапуск сервисов, или просто пишет вам письмо. Им я бы проверял пинги до гугла и время загрузки главной страницы, например.

Comment: Я ставил на сервере munin, однако видимо я его неправильно настроил, так как munin-node занимал достаточно много ресурсов, и мне пришлось его удалить. И, несмотря на то что графики действительно интересные - не дают понять в чем именно проблема, только оценить загруженность памяти, процессора и т.д.

Comment: Есть вероятность, что непосредственно перед тормозами, например, MySQL начинает жрать больше и больше памяти. Дайте второй шанс мунину, он не ест память в нормальных условиях. И настройте мониторинг всех доступных сервисов и параметров.